# ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm using code identical to my password_reset code for my email change code.
User wants change their email address so they type in their email address click a button and they're logged out.

An email is sent to them containing a link they click containing a code as id which is then matched up with the one stored in the db to confirm they are in fact the accounts owner. Any way when I click the I get the error shown below.

Problem is I'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError in EmailsController#edit

comparison of String with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed
Rails.root: /Users/greg/site

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:19:in `<'
app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:19:in `edit'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"KdFTTeWuOGqpDm6F_iY7aw"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Emails controller create:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email_change][:email])
    logout if logged_in? 
    @user.generate_and_store_email_change_token && UserMailer.email_change(@user).deliver if @user
    flash[:success] = "Email sent with email reset instructions."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Emails controller edit:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_email_change_token(params[:id])
    if @user.nil?   
      flash[:error] = "The email change link you clicked has been used."
      redirect_to root_url 
    elsif @user.email_change_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
      flash[:error] = "Email change token has expired."
      redirect_to email_change_url
    end
  end
```

User model:

```
  def generate_and_store_email_change_token
      self.email_change_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      self.email_change_sent_at = Time.zone.now
      save!(:validate => false)
  end

  def remove_used_email_change_token
      self.email_change_token = nil
      save!(:validate => false)
  end
```

This is strange because the exact same code works for my password reset. I tested again and I don't get the error the email version giving me.

Kind regards

Comment: what the type of `email_change_sent_at`? are you sure it's datetime?

Comment: Ahh yes! That explains it now, with out me even testing. I actually remember creating the migration and setting the attribute type yesterday to string. Let me test to confirm.

Comment: Thanks error is gone! Maybe you can post your answer and I can accept it and mark you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `email_change_sent_at` type is a `string`. You should change it to `datetime`